# htaccess simple rewrite doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can anyone see why this doesn't redirect?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^case-studies(/)?$ index.php/portfolio/ [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Fyi, although it shouldn't matter, I'm using Zend framework, just need to mask the '/portfolio' to '/case-studies' (picky client!)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change `/portfolio` to `/case-studies`, then you need to reverse the order:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio(/)?$ index.php/case-studies/ [NC,L]
```

Comment: Sorry my words are a bit mixed up (late Friday nite to blame), I mean't the current url is /portfolio i need it to be /case-studies

Comment: Yes, I think he got that, because what he's saying is correct.  If you want to redirect /portfolio to /case-studies then you need to reverse the order.

Comment: Yea, I don't I want that. I want /case-studies to serve the content under /portfolio (no redirect)

Comment: Try this then: `RewriteRule ^case-studies/(.*)$ portfolio/$1 [NC,L]`. Note that Zend might interfere with this.